# python: simple boolean variable declaration after for loop isn't working

Tags: python

I think the title says it all so here's the code:

```
for x in range(2, 10):
    my_button.push(button(10+50*x,470,45,20,(128,64,224),"Button ".join(chr(48+x)))

ispressed = False
```

and result:

```
jdd:my project Me$ python testbutton1.py
  File "testbutton1.py", line 81
    ispressed = False
            ^
```

I'm still learning and the syntax can be sneaky in this language. I do not know. I'm not seeing what I did wrong. The for loop is creating and pushing button objects onto a linked list.

Comment: you're missing some `))` at the line before

Comment: `"Button ".join(chr(48+x))` almost certainly does not do what you're trying to do.

Comment: &user2357112 - ok. I seem to be having trouble with the string conversion process. I know how to write a convertnum(int) function, but how do I properly concatenate a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is far too often the case with syntax errors, the problem is actually on the line preceding the error. You're missing a close parenthesis here:

```
my_button.push(button(10+50*x,470,45,20,(128,64,224),"Button ".join(chr(48+x))) )
                                                        # added this for you ---^
```

It's possible (and unknowable by all but you), that the extra close parenthesis needs to be somewhere other than the end of the line

Frankly, it'd be nice if Python included something to that effect in the traceback. Something like:

> Syntax error on line 2 of statement inside parenthetical

These errors crop up far too often, and the error is misleading. And it's not just a rookie mistake. (We all forget to close parentheses from time to time